# How to supply metadata about the promises when calling Promise.all()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, promise, metadata

I'm working on some Javascript code that looks like this:

```
const arrayOfPromises = getArrayOfPromises();
Promise.all(arrayOfPromises).then(array => doStuff(array));
```

I need to change `getArrayOfPromises()` to return some information about each promise - for simplicity, let's say it's a simple true/false flag for each. My first instinct was to refactor this function to return an array of objects instead, e.g:

```
const getArrayOfObjects = () => {
    ...
    return [
             { promise: promise1, flag: flag1 },
             { promise: promise2, flag: flag2 },
             ...
             { promise: promisen, flag: flagn }
           ];
}
```

However, the above wouldn't work with `Promise.all` because it only works directly with an iterable of Promise objects without the wrapper objects in between.

What's the simplest way to supply such metadata for each of the promises and then work with it once all the promises have been resolved?

Comment: The simplest way is to put it in a separate array and use the iteration index inside `doStuff`

Comment: @ChrisG Not sure how the separate array would be returned - could you post example code as an answer? (Also a little concerned it wouldn't be very memory-efficient but might be misunderstanding.)

Comment: 1. `return { arrayOfPromises: [...], arrayOfFlags: [...] }`; 2. `const { arrayOfPromises, arrayOfFlags } = getArrayOfObjects();` 3. `doStuff(array, arrayOfFlags)`

Comment: What exactly is that "*information about the promise*", and where/how will it be used?

Comment: @Bergi I'm using NodeGit. Each promise is a result from [`ConvenientPatch#hunks`](https://www.nodegit.org/api/convenient_patch/#hunks) and the metadata is information about the file from which the hunks originated (e.g. filename, path etc.) But none of this should matter for answering the question other than I don't have access to modify the promises themselves.

Comment: @ChrisG Still don't understand how I'd hook in `Promises.all` with the above code. (To reduce the size of this thread probably better to post as an answer that can be commented on.)

Comment: Here's what I suggested: https://jsfiddle.net/uf49rc8x/ (should use way less memory than a bunch of new promises, too)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use this meta data once the promises have been resolved and you don't have any control over the values that are being resolved by the promises returned from `getArrayOfPromises()`, then you can simply call `then()` on every separate promise in the array and make it return the original value combined with your meta data. Though make sure you replace the original promise with the promise returned by the `.then()`. `Array.prototype.map()` makes this easy:

```
arrayOfPromises = arrayOfPromises.map(promise => promise.then(value => ({
  value,
  flag: true
})));
```

Example:

```js
let arrayOfPromises = getArrayOfPromises();
arrayOfPromises = arrayOfPromises.map(promise => promise.then(value => ({
  value,
  flag: true
})));

Promise.all(arrayOfPromises).then(array => doStuff(array));

function getArrayOfPromises() {
  return [sleep(1000), sleep(1500), sleep(2000)];
}

function doStuff(array) {
  console.log(array);
}

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve('resolved after ' + ms), ms));
}
```

If you *do* have control over what `getArrayOfPromises()` returns, then simply return the meta data as part of the value that is being resolved.

Comment: Perfect! You were right in guessing I don't have control over the promises/results themselves. Have now applied the mapping method and it's working very nicely.

Answer (score 0):

> What's the simplest way to supply such metadata for each of the promises and then work with it once all the promises have been resolved?

Just put the data in each result value. It's not metadata about the promise, but about the value (?), and you don't need to work with it until all promises are resolve, so the results are the perfect place. The flags just become contents of the `array` that `Promise.all(…)` resolves to.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the result values themselves as the promises come from function calls on a third party library.

Comment: @SteveChambers Doesn't matter, just wrap them in your own `function(meta) { return thirdParty(meta).then(value => ({value, meta})); }`

Comment: Thanks, yes that's what I'm now doing (from Ivar's answer) - the key thing being a whole new set of Promises is being created, which I hadn't gleaned from your original answer.